# Find the cuboid with maximum volume

Tags: calculus, optimization

We consider a cuboid with a square base. Find the one with maximum volume if we assume that a sum of a height and a square base perimeter is smaller or equal to 108.

I know how to solve this when $H+4a=108$, but how to do this if $H+4a \le 108$?

I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: so is $$V=a^2H$$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a **hint**. 
You solved the problem of finding the maximum volume under the constraint $$H + 4a = 108$$

Now one considers the inequality constraint $$ H + 4a \leq 108$$

The maximum-volume cuboid will be found for a certain value $\alpha$ such that $$H + 4a = \alpha$$ and $ \alpha \leq 108$

But if $\alpha < 108$ is it or not conveninient to consider a larger $\alpha$? The volume is monotonically increasing in both perimeter of the square base and height.

Comment: Thanks. So I can conclude that since the volume is monotonically in both parameters the larger $H+4a$ is, the larger is the volume?

Comment: Indeed. Given the maximim volume cuboid for s value of$H +4a $, given a larger value one can just increase the height, or the base side lenght accordingly, and get a larger volume.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Set: $a=x$, $H=y$ and try to vizualise the problem on $x-y$ cartesian plane, thus:

1. the **volume** is given by: $V(x,y)=a^2H=x^2y$
2. the **constrain** is: $H+4a\leq108 \implies y+4x\leq108, \ x>0 \ y>0$

Try to visualize and plot the constrain in the plane.

For a fixed Volume $V=k$ you can also plot the curve $$\frac{k}{x^2}$$

In thi case it's easy to check that the volume attains the maximum when that curve is **tangent to the domain of the constrain**, i.e. the line: $$y+4x=108$$

Here below a **plot for k=8000**

[image]

Here below a **plot for k=16000**

[image]

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-4x%2B108,+16000%2Fx%5E2++x%3D0..120+y%3D0..120